What steps should I take to address the issue of installing h5py using pip?
I am facing an issue while trying to install packages with pip on Debian 12 and I'm unsure how to address it. As an illustration, here is what occurs when I attempt to install h5py and other packages:
pip install h5py
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
DEPRECATION: Loading egg at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/PyPDF3-1.0.6-py3.11.egg is deprecated. pip 24.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12330
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /home/merix/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (3.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from h5py) (1.24.2)
WARNING: Error parsing dependencies of send2trash: Expected matching RIGHT_PARENTHESIS for LEFT_PARENTHESIS, after version specifier
    sys-platform (=="darwin") ; extra == 'objc'


I tried installing packages still via commands:
git clone "https://github.com/h5py/h5py.git"
cd h5py
pip install .

However, this fix was only effective for packages aside from h5py.
I would appreciate any advice on installing h5py and other packages.

$ conda install h5py

I tried to install conda but it doesn't work on my computer / can't get it installed and working.

Use the system package: sudo apt install python3-h5py

I am not sure what the question is about. -- First of all: StackOverflow is not the place for personal technical assistance. -- Second: you are not showing what the issue really is, you show a warning but no error message. -- So what is the issue? What is your one question?

It worked for me. I am using Debian 12, Bookworm, and Raspberry Pi 5.
 supra@supra:~ $ sudo apt install python3-h5py

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
> state information... Done The following packages were automatically
> installed and are no longer required:   chromium-browser
> chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
> linux-headers-6.6.31+rpt-common-rpi  
> linux-headers-6.6.31+rpt-rpi-2712 linux-headers-6.6.31+rpt-rpi-v8
> linux-image-6.6.31+rpt-rpi-2712   linux-image-6.6.31+rpt-rpi-v8
> linux-kbuild-6.6.31+rpt Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. The
> following additional packages will be installed:   liblzf1
> python3-h5py-serial Suggested packages:   python-h5py-doc The
> following NEW packages will be installed:   liblzf1 python3-h5py
> python3-h5py-serial 0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0
> not upgraded.

Try this:
sudo apt install python3-h5py


https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431897/edits-that-change-the-style-wording-of-questions-potentially-with-ai
